# Using [] notation to set/get elements causes warnings

Tags: c, pointers

For the line `str[i] = temp[i];` and `temp[len-i-1] = str[i];` below, I'm getting the warning

`src/my_string.c:191:16: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion] str[i] = temp[i]; ^ ~~~~~~~ *`
and

`warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion] temp[len-i-1] = str[i]; ^ ~~~~~~ &`
respectively.

But I don't see anything wrong, as str is a pointer, and we are allowed to use [] to dereference the pointer with an offset, and temp as a char* should also work with [] notation?

```
// reverse a string
char* my_strrev(char* str){
    int len = my_strlen(str), i = 0;
    
    char* temp[len];
    
    for(i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        temp[len-i-1] = str[i];     //here
    }
    

    for(i = 0; i< len; i++){      
        str[i] = temp[i];        // and here
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: try:     char temp[len];

Comment: Ask yourself this (and pay close attention), what is the type of `str` and what is the type of `temp`?

Comment: @JeffMercado str is a pointer to a character, and temp is an array of pointers to characters?

Comment: @robthebloke oops, temp is an array of pointers to characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting warning because your temp is an array of character pointers .No need to return str in function my_strrev because in call by reference changes made using pointer reflect directly in actual argument means also change elements of s in main.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void my_strrev(char* str){
    int len = strlen(str), i = 0;
    char temp[len];
    
    for(i=len - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        temp[len-i-1] = str[i];    
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i< len; i++){      
        str[i] = temp[i];        
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char s[10];
    printf("Enter string : \n");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("\nEntered string is : %s\n",s);
    my_strrev(s);
    printf("\nReversed string is : %s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```